# Optimisation / linear programming: Why is my linear programming model for diet cost optimization unfeasible?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

The comments in [Optimisation of food items problem - how do I find the cheapest combination?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562229/optimisation-of-food-items-problem-how-do-i-find-the-cheapest-combination) and [Optimisation / linear programming: can I specify combinatorial constraints?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564005/optimisation-linear-programming-can-i-specify-combinatorial-constraints) have been very helpful.

I have tried solving this with Solver add-in in Excel using the Simplex method, but I am having a no feasible solution outcome. Why is this so and is there any way to make it feasible?

To recap: I have P number of food items to choose from, and my objective is to minimise cost ie find the quantities of each of these food items (say in grams) that I should be buying (and consuming) such that my cost is minimised, subject to the constraint that these food items fulfil my nutritional needs. I have found this is by and large a linear programming problem.

My problem has now evolved into one in which I have to take into account that I need combinations of food items that are *different* day to day so I don't get bored. I do not mind my menu recurring as long as it is not recurring every day, so I can set it say to 7 different combinations of food, 1 for 1 day of the week, and set the objective to minimise cost *per week*. Hence I now have $P \cdot Q$ variables where $P$ is the number of food items to choose from and $Q$ is the number of days.

Hence if $P = 10, Q = 7$, I have 70 variables. If my daily nutritional requirement specifies that I need N<sub>min</sub> to N<sub>max</sub> protein, C<sub>min</sub> to C<sub>max</sub> carbs, and F<sub>min</sub> to F<sub>max</sub> fat a day, then I should have $7 \cdot  3 \cdot 2 = 42$ inequality constraint statements, one for each day, each nutrient and max/min. So far, am I correct?

I have done this in Solver, and it says that there is no feasible solution.

This is the model I used:

Let i<sub>P,Q</sub> be the quantity of the Pth food item for the Qth combination.
Let D<sub>P</sub> be the cost of the Pth food item per unit quantity.

Minimise: D<sub>1</sub>i<sub>1,1</sub> + D<sub>2</sub>i<sub>2,1</sub> ... + D<sub>P</sub>i<sub>P,Q</sub>

Subject to:

**Constraints related to nutritional needs**

N<sub>1,1</sub>i<sub>1,1</sub> + N<sub>2,1</sub>i<sub>2,1</sub> ... + N<sub>P,1</sub>i<sub>P,1</sub> <= N<sub>max</sub>

N<sub>1,1</sub>i<sub>1,1</sub> + N<sub>2,1</sub>i<sub>2,1</sub> ... + N<sub>P,1</sub>i<sub>P,1</sub> >= N<sub>min</sub>

C<sub>1,1</sub>i<sub>1,1</sub> + C<sub>2,1</sub>i<sub>2,1</sub> ... + C<sub>P,1</sub>i<sub>P,1</sub> <= C<sub>max</sub>

C<sub>1,1</sub>i<sub>1,1</sub> + C<sub>2,1</sub>i<sub>2,1</sub> ... + C<sub>P,1</sub>i<sub>P,1</sub> >= C<sub>min</sub>

F<sub>1,1</sub>i<sub>1,1</sub> + F<sub>2,1</sub>i<sub>2,1</sub> ... + F<sub>P,1</sub>i<sub>P,1</sub> <= F<sub>max</sub>

F<sub>1,1</sub>i<sub>1,1</sub> + F<sub>2,1</sub>i<sub>2,1</sub> ... + F<sub>P,1</sub>i<sub>P,1</sub> >= F<sub>min</sub>

...

N<sub>1,Q</sub>i<sub>1,Q</sub> + N<sub>2,Q</sub>i<sub>2,Q</sub> ... + N<sub>P,Q</sub>i<sub>P,Q</sub> <= N<sub>max</sub>

N<sub>1,Q</sub>i<sub>1,Q</sub> + N<sub>2,Q</sub>i<sub>2,Q</sub> ... + N<sub>P,Q</sub>i<sub>P,Q</sub> >= N<sub>min</sub>

C<sub>1,Q</sub>i<sub>1,Q</sub> + C<sub>2,Q</sub>i<sub>2,Q</sub> ... + C<sub>P,Q</sub>i<sub>P,Q</sub> <= C<sub>max</sub>

C<sub>1,Q</sub>i<sub>1,Q</sub> + C<sub>2,Q</sub>i<sub>2,Q</sub> ... + C<sub>P,Q</sub>i<sub>P,Q</sub> >= C<sub>min</sub>

F<sub>1,Q</sub>i<sub>1,Q</sub> + F<sub>2,Q</sub>i<sub>2,Q</sub> ... + F<sub>P,Q</sub>i<sub>P,Q</sub> <= F<sub>max</sub>

F<sub>1,Q</sub>i<sub>1,Q</sub> + F<sub>2,Q</sub>i<sub>2,Q</sub> ... + F<sub>P,Q</sub>i<sub>P,Q</sub> >= F<sub>min</sub>

***Combinatorial Constraints***

(As I am not completely familiar with decision binary variables I do not know how to write this properly in math notation. However, I am already getting a non-feasibility outcome with only the above linear constraints.)

I have also used equality constraints, instead of using min/max constraints and I still have the same non-feasibility outcome. Why is this so? Is it really infeasible? Should I change the algorithm? Solver add-in in Excel does not seem to support any other LP solving algorithm other than Simplex though. If I use Gurobi, will it solve the problem?

Comment: "*I have done this in Solver, ...*" Where is your mathematical model? Make it as small/simple as possible in order to make it easy to formulate and to comprehend the model formulation.

Comment: @callculus by "where is your mathematical model" do you mean I should be uploading it here?

Comment: Yes, Otherwise it is not possible to know what you´re talking about.

Comment: @callculus ok pardon me but how do I upload an .xls file on Math SE? tried searching for instructions, but I can't find any

Comment: By a "mathematical model" we mean something looking like in equation (2.1) here https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/linear.html#basic-notions or like the multiline displayed math block in example 2.9 in section https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/linear.html#dual-values-as-shadow-prices

Comment: @forgodsakehold You are able to  upload pictures only.

Comment: @forgodsakehold I´ve noticed your model. You wrote that you´ve reduced your model. I appreciate that you have tried to simplify your model. But I´ve to admit it is still too complex for me at the first view. Hopefully there is somebody else who can help you.

Comment: What makes you think there should be a feasible solution? Is it clear that there should be one? Maybe the constraints just can't be satisfied.